# Document.Write com variável não imprime

Tags: javascript, html, table

Por que o `window.document.write(valores)` nem o `$("body").append(valores)` não imprimem na tela?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/media/images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://www.datatables.net/rss.xml">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">


    <title>custom-ajax</title>

</head>
<body>

 <table class="table table-hover" style ="margin-top: 200px">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th style ="color: blue">RE</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
      <th>Escala</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
       <td>4x2</td>
    </tr>

<script>
var valores = "";

             $.ajax({
                     dataType:'json',
                     url : './TableData',
                     type : 'GET' ,                

                    success: function(dados) {

                        queryObject = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(dados) + ')');
                        queryObjectLen = queryObject.jsonArray.length;

                       //alert(queryObjectLen.toString());
                        for(var i=0;i<queryObjectLen;i++){ 



                    var nome = queryObject.jsonArray[i].nome;
                    var escala = queryObject.jsonArray[i].escala;


                      valores = valores+"<tr><td>100</td>";
                      valores = valores+"<td>"+nome+"</td>";
                      valores = valores+"<td>123@</td>";
                      valores = valores+"<td>"+escala+"</td></tr>";

                }

            },

                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {

                        alert("erro:"+status+" "+ error);
                    }

                });
     $( "body" ).append(valores);
     window.document.write(valores);
     //window.document.write("<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>");
</script>
    <tr>      
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td>4x2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>  
      <td colspan="2">#</td>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>#</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem querer entrar em detalhes da qualidade do código, o problema apenas está ligado ao fato de você estar colocando o código:

```
$( "body" ).append(valores);
window.document.write(valores);
```

fora do Ajax, logo, no carregamento da página, a variável `valores` está vazia, e só depois no retorno do Ajax ela terá valor, porque o Ajax funciona **sem** sincronia com o carregamento da página.

Coloque esse código no final do `success` do Ajax, mas não use `document.write`, porque neste caso ele irá sobrescrever toda a página.

Outra coisa é que não faz sentido colocar o `script` no meio da tabela.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, qual seria a melhor forma de pegar os valores do AJAX e montar a tabela?

Comment: Cara, basicamente você monta a tabela sem as linhas que virão do Ajax, e depois no retorno do Ajax vc vai usando append para adicionar as linhas na tabela.

Comment: Ok, obrigado! Vou estudar o append para popular a tabela. Valeu!

Comment: Se tiver alguma duvida, pode perguntar ou abrir uma nova pergunta. Abs!